# How can I create a reference to an object in my main function (given the user input) (Java)?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm making a class `Usuario` which is stored in an `ArrayList` in another class called `Usuarios` and I'm trying to make a code that allows the user to type his name and the object of the class `Usuario` is stored in a variable called `usuario_logado` for further occasions.

Here is my `Usuarios` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class Usuarios {
    private static ArrayList<Usuario> UsersList = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    public static ArrayList<Usuario> getUsuarios(){
        return Usuarios.UsersList;
    }

    public static void addUser(Usuario u){
        UsersList.add(u);
    } 
}
```

Here is my `Usuario` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
/**
 * Usuario
 */
public class Usuario {

    private static int indexes = 0;
    private int index;
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    public Usuario(){
    }
    
    public Usuario(String nome, String email){
       
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        Usuarios.addUser(this);
        this.index = indexes;
        indexes++;
    }
    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return "Nome : " + this.nome + " E-mail : " + this.email + " index:" + this.index; 
    }
}
```

And here is the main function in the class app:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario user0 = new Usuario("None", "None");
        Usuario user1 = new Usuario("Thomas", "anotheremail@hotmail.com");
        Usuario user2 = new Usuario("juao", "juaozinhogeimepleis@hotmail.com");
        Usuario user3 = new Usuario("marcia", "jooj@hotmail.com");
        Usuario user4 = new Usuario("Ednaldo", "valenada@hotmail.com");
        Usuario user5 = new Usuario("Fausto", "olokobixo@hotmail.com");
       
        Usuario usuario_logado = new Usuario();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Login \n Username :");
        String nome = input.next();

        for(Usuario user : Usuarios.getUsuarios()){
            if(user.getNome().equals(nome)){
                usuario_logado = user;
            }
        }
        usuario_logado.getString(); 
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can store the usuario(user) in the main function?

Comment: Remove all `static`s from your class `Usuarios`, create an instance of `Usuarios` in your `main` and call `addUser` for each of your `Usuario` instances. Also, you're asking *"How can I create a reference to an object in my main function"*, but you're already creating instances of other objects. It's no different for the `Usuarios` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a couple of changes to your code. First, remove the static variable in `Usuarios` and make it an instance variable:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Usuarios {
    private List<Usuario> usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios(){
        return usersList;
    }

    public void addUser(Usuario u){
        usersList.add(u);
    }
}
```

Additionally, remove the line `Usuarios.addUser(this);` in `Usuario` as follows:

```java
public class Usuario {

    private static int indexes = 0;
    private int index;
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    public Usuario(){
    }

    public Usuario(String nome, String email){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.index = indexes;
        indexes++;
    }
    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return "Nome : " + this.nome + " E-mail : " + this.email + " index:" + this.index;
    }
}
```

And finally, the most important thing, change your main class so that you create an instance of `Usuarios` and add each and every `Usuario` that you create to that `Usuarios` instance as follows:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usuarios users = new Usuarios();
        Usuario user0 = new Usuario("None", "None");
        users.addUser(user0);
        Usuario user1 = new Usuario("Thomas", "anotheremail@hotmail.com");
        users.addUser(user1);
        Usuario user2 = new Usuario("juao", "juaozinhogeimepleis@hotmail.com");
        users.addUser(user2);
        Usuario user3 = new Usuario("marcia", "jooj@hotmail.com");
        users.addUser(user3);
        Usuario user4 = new Usuario("Ednaldo", "valenada@hotmail.com");
        users.addUser(user4);
        Usuario user5 = new Usuario("Fausto", "olokobixo@hotmail.com");
        users.addUser(user5);

        Usuario usuario_logado = new Usuario();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Login \n Username :");
        String nome = input.next();

        for(Usuario user : users.getUsuarios()){
            if(user.getNome().equals(nome)){
                usuario_logado = user;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(usuario_logado.getString());
    }
}
```